# Invalid Markup when using Validation.Error in WPF style

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, visual-studio-2012, resourcedictionary

I am trying to apply the attached event Validation.Error to a number of elements within a wpf window using a style.

Example of how implemented:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <EventSetter Event="Validation.Error" Handler="TextBox_ValidationError"/>
</Style>
```

This code works and the handler method is called when a validation error occurs.

However the designer in VS2012 won't show and gives the message 'Invalid Markup' with the error message: "The event 'Error' is not a RoutedEvent."

In VS2010 I get the same error message but the designer still works.

I am using styles as my real program uses a DataGrid and styles are being applied through EditingElementStyle.

Any ideas on how to fix up the style?

Comment: Seems fine here, VS2010 and VS2012

Comment: You get now errors at all? I'm using VS2012 update 3.

Comment: None, I also am running VS2012 update 3, and 2010 is fine too

Comment: Here is a screen shot:http://i.imgur.com/Dv9HdPs.png  Am I doing something different to you.

Comment: I copied exactly what you have in the image and no errors, Have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: Yep have restarted VS multiple times now.

Comment: I had a chat to the guys here at work and they have never seen this error either, but they also mention issues like this can occur when you solution is on a network drive/share, also I remember having strange xaml issues years ago when I installed an app called Resharper a lot of people use it (I can’t stand it) but maybe that could be it if you use it, otherwise I have no idea, very strange